Visual Studio 2022 how to add IConfiguration (appsettings.json) into IntelliSense for autocomplete
I'm looking to see if there's a way within Visual Studio 2022 to get IntelliSense to be able to access all of the options within my appsettings.json if the object type is an IConfiguration type.
I'm using appsettings.json for a few global variables and don't want to keep accessing the JSON file to get the right names. I hope there's an addon/option to get IntelliSense to see all of the JSON names.
For example, I could start typing within the "" and then tab complete to the available name, if after that I type: IntelliSense would look for the name pairs under the current name in the JSON file.

even with the traditional XML .config files, most of the time you refer to the AppSetting with a string [eg: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["settingKey"]; ] in C#. I believe that VB has a means to do it [somthing like My.Settings.SettingKey]. Either way, this question is offtopic for being about programming, and being a request for a software product recommendation. maybe a better fit for SO.
